Can there exist $X$ with $X \wedge X \cong S_s^1 \wedge S_t^1$ in motivic homotopy theory?
In the context of motivic homotopy theory, we have $\operatorname{Spc}(k) = \Delta^{\operatorname{op}} \operatorname{Shv}_{\operatorname{Nis}}(\operatorname{Sm}/k)$. Let $S_s^1$ be the simplicial sphere and $S_t^1$ be the Tate sphere. Can there exist some $X \in \operatorname{Spc}(k)$ with $X \wedge X \cong S_s^1 \wedge S_t^1$?
